# can't secure my path with silex securityServiceProvider

Tags: php, security, silex

I am trying to build a simple authentication code for my Silex app but I can't make it work.

I spent hours trying to figure out where is the mistake but can't find it..
Here is the code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
   'security.firewalls' =>  array(
       'admin' => array(
           'pattern' => '^/admin.*',
           'http' => true,
           'form' => array(
               'login_path' => '/login',
               'check_path' => '/admin/login_check',
           ),
           'logout' => array(
               'logout_path' => '/admin/logout',
               'invalidate_session' => true
           ),
           'users' => $usersData,
       ),
    )
));

$app->get('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.html', array(
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']-     >get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
});
```

The app is not blocking any path, I really don't understand what I'm missing as I already did this in another app and everything works fine there...

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: $usersData is defined somewhere?(anyway you need to choose between 'http' and 'form' in the security firewall, you can't have both)

Comment: Thank you for help @fain182 , $usersData is retrived from database, when I dump it I get: `array(1) { ["admin"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN" [1]=> string(88) "5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg==" } }`

Comment: also I switched http to false but seems like nothing changed.. regex works as expected as the other Symfony components I'm using (User).

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the provisioning of my vagrant machine, rebuilt everything from scratch and now it works flawlessly.